# jQuery mouseleave for touch screen / tablets

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a modal box which fades in on `mouseenter` and fades out on `mouseleave`. The only problem is when using a touch screen device such as a tablet, I can't get the modal to `fadeout` once it's showing on the page. Is there any way of modifying this code to where anytime the user touches outside the modal box it will `fadeout`?

```
$(".tiptrigger").mouseenter(function() { 

    var s_id = $(this).attr('id'); // There may be more than one per page
    $("#tiptip_holder-"+s_id).fadeIn("fast");   

}); 

$(".tiptrigger").mouseleave(function() { 

    var s_id = $(this).attr('id');
    $("#tiptip_holder-"+s_id).fadeOut("slow");

});
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can try using touch events (not tested):

```
$('.tiptrigger').on('mouseenter touchstart', function(){ 
    var s_id = $(this).attr('id'); // There may be more than one per page
    $("#tiptip_holder-"+s_id).fadeIn("fast"); 
});

$('.tiptrigger').on('mouseleave touchend', function(){
    var s_id = $(this).attr('id');
    $("#tiptip_holder-"+s_id).fadeOut("slow");
});
```

### EDIT

You can try:

```
$('.tiptrigger').on('mouseenter touchstart', function(e){ 
    var s_id = $(this).attr('id'); // There may be more than one per page
    $("#tiptip_holder-"+s_id).fadeIn("fast"); 
    e.stopPropagation()
});

$('.tiptrigger').on('mouseleave', function(e){
    var s_id = $(this).attr('id');
    $("#tiptip_holder-"+s_id).fadeOut("slow");
});

$('body').on('touchstart', function(e){ 
    $("div[id^='tiptip_holder']").fadeOut("slow");        
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but Im trying to get anytime the user touches the page, if the modal is visible then hide it.

Comment: You want to close any tiptip holder that can be opened?

Comment: Yes, if any tiptop_holder is visible, I want to hide all of them when the body is touched. Ive been trying with it, but after it hides once, I can't get it to reappear.

Comment: Thanks a ton! The problem with body touchstart is that the .tiptrigger is located within the body, so now it's trying to open and close at the same time. Is there a way, instead of `$('body').on('touchstart')` to basically state if anything is touched besides `.tiptrigger`? That should do it.

Comment: I need yo know how it works, is it opening an overlay div? Can you provide a quick sample on jsfiddle?

Comment: All of the divs are on the page, but hidden.

Answer (score 10):

mouseMouse events (`mouseover`, `mouseout`, `mousedown`, `mouseup`, `mousemove`, etc) are specific to the mouse input device. The keyboard has `keydown`, `keypress` and `keyup`. Touch has `touchstart`, `touchmove`, `touchend` and `touchcancel`. Webkit on the iPhone/iPad/etc has additional gesture start/move/end events that are Apple-specific.

Thus you should be checking for the device on which you are running the app and then handle the code accordingly.